# c# try and catch + variables outside

Tags: c#, try-catch

how can i get the variables x,y and z outside the try-catch?

This is my code:

```
public static void mudarSpawn_1(GtaPlayer player, string coordenadas)
{
    char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',' };
    string text = coordenadas;
    string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);
    try
    {
         float x = float.Parse(words[0], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
         float y = float.Parse(words[1], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
         float z = float.Parse(words[1], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        player.SendClientMessage(Color.DarkOrange, "Os valores de x,y e z não foram inseridos de forma correcta, apenas podes usar numeros");
        player.SendClientMessage(Color.DarkOrange, "Ex: /mudarspawn3 6321.6 , 96321.38 , 66322.2 ou /mudarspawn3 6321.6 96321.38 66322.2");
    }

    MSGameMysql.mudarspawn1(x, y, z);
    player.SendClientMessage(Color.AliceBlue, "Acabaste de mudar o spawn 1 para: x='" + x + "' y='" + y + "' z='" + z + "'");
}
```

The

```
MSGameMysql.mudarspawn1(x, y, z);
player.SendClientMessage(Color.AliceBlue, "Acabaste de mudar o spawn 1 para: x='" + x + "' y='" + y + "' z='" + z + "'");
```

this x y and z vars inside of the mudarspawn1() are returing as x = 0 y = 0 and z = 0

How can i fix this?

i tried to do a set and get... but no happy ending.

The main use is:
The player write /mudarspawn1 [coordenadas]

Ex: /mudarspawn1 656.32 65.21 698.1

But if they use chars, the program will get an error and i want to send a chat to them telling that they can only use numbers.

Comment: Declare them before the `try`... Or rather use TryParse().

Comment: the variables are declared inside the try catch, so that's where their scope is. you can declare them before the try catch and just set their values inside

Comment: Whilst your problem is clear to anyone reading, it's worth noting that your code as written *doesn't compile* as `x`, `y` and `z` are out of scope where you say their values are zero. Posting your actual code (and reading the error message it would give you on compilation!) would have been a big step toward solving your own problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to declare and initialize them before the `try` scope:

```
    float x = 0f;
    float y = 0f;
    float z = 0f;
    try
    {
         x = float.Parse(words[0], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
         y = float.Parse(words[1], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
         z = float.Parse(words[1], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        player.SendClientMessage(Color.DarkOrange, "Os valores de x,y e z não foram inseridos de forma correcta, apenas podes usar numeros");
        player.SendClientMessage(Color.DarkOrange, "Ex: /mudarspawn3 6321.6 , 96321.38 , 66322.2 ou /mudarspawn3 6321.6 96321.38 66322.2");
    }

    MSGameMysql.mudarspawn1(x, y, z);
    player.SendClientMessage(Color.AliceBlue, "Acabaste de mudar o spawn 1 para: x='" + x + "' y='" + y + "' z='" + z + "'");
```

However, you'd be better off looking into `float.TryParse()` and not using exception handling here (which may give you undesired results).  For example,

```
float x;
if (!float.TryParse(words[0], NumberStyles.AllowThousands || NumberStyles.Float, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out x))
{
   // unable to parse words[0] as a float, handle it here.
}
```

Comment: Yep, `TryParse` is the way to go here.

Comment: I will try that one too, i think its more simple to use the TryPrase :D

Comment: You should also check to make sure `words` has at least two entries - again, rathe rthan relying on exception handling.

Comment: @ Dan Field

 how can i use just that if to all of them, im doing something like this

`if(!float.TryParse(words[0], out x))
            {
                
            }`

Comment: Do that for each one.  It looks like you set `y` and `z`, so you probably don't even need z - just pass y twice to the last method.

Answer (score 3):

> how can i get the variables x,y and z outside the try-catch?

Declare them outside the `try...catch` but set them inside it e.g.

```
float x = 0f; 
float y = 0f;
float z = 0f;
try
{
     x = float.Parse(...);
     y = float.Parse(...);
     z = float.Parse(...);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare them outside and assing them inside

```
float x;
float y;
float z;

try
{
   x = float.Parse(words[0], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   y = float.Parse(words[1], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   z = float.Parse(words[1], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 }
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that you looking for,

```
        public static void mudarSpawn_1(GtaPlayer player, string coordenadas)
        {
            char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',' };
            string text = coordenadas;
            string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);
            float x = new float();
            float y = new float();
            float z = new float();
            try
            {
                x = float.Parse(words[0], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                y = float.Parse(words[1], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                z = float.Parse(words[1], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                player.SendClientMessage(Color.DarkOrange, "Os valores de x,y e z não foram inseridos de forma correcta, apenas podes usar numeros");
                player.SendClientMessage(Color.DarkOrange, "Ex: /mudarspawn3 6321.6 , 96321.38 , 66322.2 ou /mudarspawn3 6321.6 96321.38 66322.2");
            }

            MSGameMysql.mudarspawn1(x, y, z);
            player.SendClientMessage(Color.AliceBlue, "Acabaste de mudar o spawn 1 para: x='" + x + "' y='" + y + "' z='" + z + "'");


        }
```

Comment: This code will complain that you're using uninitialized variables.  You have to set them before the try scope to be ablet ouse them after.

Comment: Yes, You are absolutely correct. Sorry for my mistake. :)

Comment: Well i will test that.. the code didnt complain about that, i will report soon thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys! its working i used a if in the mudarspawn1() to handle the 0 from xy or z

```
public static void mudarspawn1(GtaPlayer player, float x, float y, float z)
    {

        if (x == 0 || y == 0 || z == 0)
        {


        }
        else
        {

            string sql = "update spawnposition set spawn_1x = '" + x + "', spawn_1y = '" + y + "', spawn_1z = '" + z + "' where id ='1'";

            try
            {

                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
                conn.Open();

                MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                player.SendClientMessage(Color.DarkOrange, "Foi adicionado o spawn 1");


            }
            catch (MySqlException e)
            {



            }
        }
```

Fixed :D